# Resampling doesn't work on the first data

Tags: python, resample

I tried to convert yearly data to monthly, starting from 2001 to 2020,
however 2001 data was not converted to monthly.

The original dataset looks like:

0  2001-12-31  16.5648   4.9887  11.1706  ...   6.4568   7.9525   7.7998  11.2796

1  2002-12-31  15.3589  14.1851  11.4080  ...   7.7080   7.6465   8.1067  11.6526

2 2003-12-31  10.0559  15.1041  11.5154  ...   8.6358   9.0530   9.4951  11.8169

3  2004-12-31  13.4166  15.6389  12.9674  ...   9.9278  10.7078  11.1832  13.0509

4  2005-12-31  13.3857  16.7083   8.9411  ...  11.0563  12.7320  11.9903  13.0580

What I tried:

```
df4['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df4['Date'])

df4 = df4.set_index('Date').resample('M').bfill().reset_index()
```

The output:

```
2001-12-31  16.5648   4.9887  11.1706  ...   7.9525   7.7998  11.2796

2002-01-31  15.3589  14.1851  11.4080  ...   7.6465   8.1067  11.6526

2002-02-28  15.3589  14.1851  11.4080  ...   7.6465   8.1067  11.6526

2002-03-31  15.3589  14.1851  11.4080  ...   7.6465   8.1067  11.6526

2002-04-30  15.3589  14.1851  11.4080  ...   7.6465   8.1067  11.6526
```

Can anybody tell me what I missed? Thank you

Comment: Please try to provide a brief statement that puts your problem in context.  Something like "I am working with data obtained from a climate data base, and now need to extract information using the Python "date time" string.   Here is what I tried :

Comment: Looks like the output is monthly data. Now I'm wondering what I've missed :D

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the df4 is yearly book value of stocks and I tried to converted it to monthly, for each month,  the book value is same as the yearly book value.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is resampling the data from yearly to monthly and then calling [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) to backwards fill the data gaps with *constant value*.

If you would like to *interpolate* the gaps, you should call [`resample('M').interpolate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) instead.

Comment: thank you very much, I guess I need set the starting date to 2001-1-31 and then backwards fill

Comment: If you do `bfill` or `fillna`, all of the months will have the same value that the year has. You probably want to just `interpolate`.